# How to import someone else's toolbox?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geoprocessing, choropleth, toolbox

I'm trying to use a toolbox created by someone at Esri to help with the creation of bivariate choropleth maps.

I'm not sure, though, how to import the toolbox and the other files so that I can use them in ArcGIS Desktop.

I downloaded and registered the renderer just fine. The author gives the link to the zip file with the geoprocessing tool but does not give directions on how to add the tool to ArcMap.

Here is link to the blog where I found out about this method:

https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2015/09/15/making-bivariate-choropleth-maps-with-arcmap/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need make connection to the folder where you have that tool. After that tool should be available in Catalog

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I came across these two resources [here](http://response.restoration.noaa.gov/aloha_arcmap) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EVPzPGW7qVo),  they are from some years back but still relevant.

Here is an excerpt:

> ```
> Launch ArcMap.
> ```

```
Right-click on the ArcMap toolbar and scroll down to
```

> "Customize" (or choose the "Customize" option under the Tools menu).

```
Select the "Commands" tab on the "Customize" window.

Click the "Add from file" button.  

Navigate to the DLL file on your hard drive. 
>(If you don't see the file, 
>your browser may not have unzipped the compressed version.)     

Select the DLL file and click Open to add the tool 
to your available tools. Click OK.  

Exit the "Customize" window.
```